# Joining Dataframes with same coumn name in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I have two dataframe which has been readed from two csv files.

```
+---+----------+-----------------+
| ID|  NUMBER  |  RECHARGE_AMOUNT|
+---+----------+-----------------+
|  1|9090909092|               30|
|  2|9090909093|               30|
|  3|9090909090|               30|
|  4|9090909094|               30|
+---+----------+-----------------+
```

and

```
+---+----------+-----------------+
| ID|  NUMBER  |  RECHARGE_AMOUNT|
+---+----------+-----------------+
|  1|9090909092|               40|
|  2|9090909093|               50|
|  3|9090909090|               60|
|  4|9090909094|               70|
+---+----------+-----------------+
```

I am triying to join this two data from using NUMBER coumn using the pyspark code `dfFinal = dfFinal.join(df2, on=['NUMBER'], how='inner')` and new dataframe is generated as follows.

```
+----------+---+-----------------+---+-----------------+
|  NUMBER  | ID|  RECHARGE_AMOUNT| ID|  RECHARGE_AMOUNT|
+----------+---+-----------------+---+-----------------+
|9090909092|  1|               30|  1|               40|
|9090909093|  2|               30|  2|               50|
|9090909090|  3|               30|  3|               60|
|9090909094|  4|               30|  4|               70|
+----------+---+-----------------+---+-----------------+
```

But i am not able to write this dataframe into a file since the dataframe after joining is having duplicate column. I am using the following code. `dfFinal.coalesce(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save('/home/user/output',header = 'true')` Is there any way to avoid duplicate column after joining in spark. Given below is my pyspark code.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test1").getOrCreate()
files = ["/home/user/test1.txt", "/home/user/test2.txt"]
dfFinal = spark.read.load(files[0],format="csv", sep=",", inferSchema="false", header="true", mode="DROPMALFORMED")
dfFinal.show()
for i in range(1,len(files)):
    df2 = spark.read.load(files[i],format="csv", sep=",", inferSchema="false", header="true", mode="DROPMALFORMED")
    df2.show()
    dfFinal = dfFinal.join(df2, on=['NUMBER'], how='inner')
dfFinal.show()
dfFinal.coalesce(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save('/home/user/output',header = 'true')
```

I need to generate unique column name.ie: if i gave two files in files array with same coumn it should generate as follows.

```
+----------+----+-------------------+-----+-------------------+
|  NUMBER  |IDx |  RECHARGE_AMOUNTx | IDy |  RECHARGE_AMOUNTy |
+----------+----+-------------------+-----+-------------------+
|9090909092|  1 |               30  |  1  |               40  |
|9090909093|  2 |               30  |  2  |               50  |
|9090909090|  3 |               30  |  3  |               60  |
|9090909094|  4 |               30  |  4  |               70  |
+----------+---+-----------------+---+------------------------+
```

In panda i can use `suffixes` argument as show below `dfFinal = dfFinal.merge(df2,left_on='NUMBER',right_on='NUMBER',how='inner',suffixes=('x', 'y'),sort=True)` which will generate the above dataframe. Is there any way i can replicate this on pyspark.

Comment: Can you please try to describe how would you like to see the output dataframe which will be saved to the file (without duplicate columns)? e.g. do you need two `ID` columns with the same ID number? would you like to rename `RECHARGE_AMOUNT` to `RECHARGE_AMOUNT_2` ? etc

Comment: Can you select only the 'NUMBER' column from your second dataframe and then do the join ? This would avoid getting columns from the second dataframe.

Comment: I updated the question.yes i like to generate unique column name.such as RECHARGE_AMOUNT_2.@Yaron

Comment: I want the ID and RECHARGE_AMOUNT coumn in first dataframe also.@Constantine

Answer (score 1):

You can select the columns from each dataframe and alias it.
Like this.

```
dfFinal = dfFinal.join(df2, on=['NUMBER'], how='inner') \
                 .select('NUMBER',
                         dfFinal.ID.alias('ID_1'),
                         dfFinal.RECHARGE_AMOUNT.alias('RECHARGE_AMOUNT_1'),
                         df2.ID.alias('ID_2'),
                         df2.RECHARGE_AMOUNT.alias('RECHARGE_AMOUNT_2'))
```