# join two dataframe the pyspark

Tags: python, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to join two dataframe the pyspark.

I am using `join`  but this multiplies the instances.

`dfResult = df1.join(df2, on='Class', how="inner")`

How could I do it?
the data is ordered in the same way in both dataframe, so I just need to literally pass a column (data3) from one dataframe to the other.

Comment: Welcome to SO, what do you mean with 'multiplies the instances'? In general you get the best answers if you provide a minimal reproducible example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I mean the number of rows of data.
In the df1 I have 150 rows / examples, just like in the df2. Well, after applying join I happen to have 20,290 rows / examples.
What I'm looking for is to keep 150 rows / examples but joining both dataframes

Comment: You will need to join the two dataframes on the key collumns, that is the combination of fields which is unique for each row. You can do so with `on=['col1', 'col2', ...]`. Currently the class column is not unique for each row causing duplication.

Comment: the class column is the only identifier, the problem is that it is not a unique id for each row, it divides the data into two classes,
There is no unique identifier for each row, apart from the fact that the data keep the same order in both dataframes.

Comment: If you have no columns to join on than this will not work. With these datasizes it will be much simpler to use pandas and append the dataframes. You can create a spark df from the resulting pandas df. However I will not be able to help you further without a proper reproducible example.

Comment: I have passed the dataframe to pandas`df1.toPandas()` , I have applied `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)` and then I have transformed them back to pyspark `spark.createDataFrame(df1)` to be able to continue working with them and it has worked for me.
Sorry for not providing a functional example but I did not know how to do it in a simple way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO! There are a few [similar questions already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52622076/joining-dataframes-with-same-coumn-name-in-pyspark). You appear to have a dataset that happens to have a few columns with the same name. It happens. However spark expects them all to be different, except the columns on which you join. You could resolve this by simply renaming the column.

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([("123456","Rose","Yellow"),("123456","Jasmine","white"),("789654","Lily","Purple")])).toDF(*["id","name","color"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([("123456","Rose","Canada"),("123456","Jasmine","US"),("333444","Lily","Purple")])).toDF(*["id","name","Place"])

df3 = df1.join(df2, on=["name"], how="inner")
df3.show()
```

The join without renaming would result in

```
+-------+------+------+------+------+
|   name|    id| color|    id| Place|
+-------+------+------+------+------+
|   Rose|123456|Yellow|123456|Canada|
|Jasmine|123456| white|123456|    US|
|   Lily|789654|Purple|333444|Purple|
+-------+------+------+------+------+
```

The join  with renaming

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, on=["name"], how="inner").select("name", "Place",df1.id.alias("id_1"), df2.id.alias("id_2"))
```

Allows you to identify which column originates from with dataset.

```
+-------+------+------+------+
|   name| Place|  id_1|  id_2|
+-------+------+------+------+
|   Rose|Canada|123456|123456|
|Jasmine|    US|123456|123456|
|   Lily|Purple|789654|333444|
+-------+------+------+------+
```